# How to deploy laravel 5.1 project to linux server?

Tags: linux, laravel, deployment

i have problem deploying my laravel web project to linux server, i have uploaded the project and also import the database. but dont know why i can not login to my the web, it says 500 'Internal server error', but doesnt show any error message.

the laravel log ever show this error

```
[2016-02-22 10:56:54] local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blogg.users' doesn't exist' in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:310
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(310): PDO->prepare('select * from `...')
    #1 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(629): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection), 'select * from `...', Array)
    #2 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(596): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #3 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(315): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #4 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1389): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
    #5 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1379): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
    #6 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1364): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->getFresh(Array)
    #7 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(409): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
    #8 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(168): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
    #9 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(140): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get(Array)
    #10 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php(100): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->first()
    #11 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php(365): Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(Array)
    #12 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php(275): Illuminate\Auth\Guard->attempt(Array, false, false)
    #13 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php(258): Illuminate\Auth\Guard->validate(Array)
    #14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Auth\Guard->once(Array)
    #15 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php(137): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #16 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/Auth/IlluminateAuthAdapter.php(31): Illuminate\Support\Manager->__call('once', Array)
    #17 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/Auth/IlluminateAuthAdapter.php(31): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->once(Array)
    #18 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWTAuth.php(99): Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\IlluminateAuthAdapter->byCredentials(Array)
    #19 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(210): Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth->attempt(Array)
    #20 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/app/Http/Controllers/TokenAuthController.php(31): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('attempt', Array)
    #21 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/app/Http/Controllers/TokenAuthController.php(31): Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::attempt(Array)
    #22 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\TokenAuthController->authenticate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #23 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(256): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #24 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(164): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('authenticate', Array)
    #25 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(112): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\TokenAuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'authenticate')
    #26 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #27 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #28 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #29 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #30 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(114): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #31 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(69): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\TokenAuthController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'authenticate')
    #32 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(201): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'authenticate')
    #33 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(134): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #34 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(704): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #35 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #36 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #37 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #38 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #39 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(706): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #40 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(671): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #41 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(631): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #42 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(236): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #43 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #44 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(139): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #45 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #46 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #47 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #48 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #49 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #50 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #51 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #52 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #53 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #54 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #55 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #56 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #57 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(42): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #58 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #59 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #60 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #61 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #62 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
    #63 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #64 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #65 {main}

    Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'blogg.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = hey limit 1)' in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:636
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(596): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #1 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(315): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #2 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1389): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
    #3 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1379): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
    #4 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1364): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->getFresh(Array)
    #5 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(409): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
    #6 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(168): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
    #7 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(140): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get(Array)
    #8 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php(100): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->first()
    #9 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php(365): Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(Array)
    #10 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php(275): Illuminate\Auth\Guard->attempt(Array, false, false)
    #11 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php(258): Illuminate\Auth\Guard->validate(Array)
    #12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Auth\Guard->once(Array)
    #13 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php(137): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #14 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/Auth/IlluminateAuthAdapter.php(31): Illuminate\Support\Manager->__call('once', Array)
    #15 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth
```

but now laravel log doesnt update anymore

anyone know what do i have to do actually?

thanks for your time

**EDIT:**

here i have created error_log file, and it says

```
[Fri Feb 26 14:47:12 2016] [error] [client 122.120.43.130] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'There is no existing directory at "/var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied' in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:141\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php(77): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->createDir()\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/fram in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 141, referer: http://myblogg.net/IMGN/public/IMGN/
[Fri Feb 26 14:47:12 2016] [error] [client 122.120.43.130] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'There is no existing directory at "/var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied' in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:141\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php(77): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->createDir()\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/http in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 141, referer: http://myblogg.net/IMGN/public/IMGN/
[Fri Feb 26 14:55:46 2016] [error] [client 122.120.43.130] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'There is no existing directory at "/var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied' in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:141\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php(77): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->createDir()\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/laravel/fram in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 141, referer: http://myblogg.net/IMGN/public/IMGN/
[Fri Feb 26 14:55:46 2016] [error] [client 122.120.43.130] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'There is no existing directory at "/var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied' in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:141\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php(77): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->createDir()\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/http in /var/www/vhosts/myblogg.net/httpdocs/IMGN/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 141, referer: http://myblogg.net/IMGN/public/IMGN/
```

Comment: `Table 'blogg.users' doesn't exist'` check if you have all this tables. If is saying no table, so there is conenction to DB.

Comment: i have checked the table users, its already exist there. but dont know why it said does not exist

Comment: Did you change DB auth info in .env file when you deployed your website to the server?

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin no, i dont change anything except DB_HOST, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, and i have just checked that there is no DB auth in .env file. for additional info, its laravel 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely having a problem with database. Check your DB settings in configuration and .env files. Also, maybe you forgot to transfer database from local to the production server?

About you problem with `monolog` logging, it could be because of permissions of `storage` folder. This can help:

```
chmod -R 775 /path_to_laravel_project/storage
```

Comment: i have checked the database, and all table seems exist. and yes that error info comes even after i change the permission like u pointed above. its now writable. do i have to do this chmod -R 775 /path_to_laravel_project/storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: Check what permissions does laravel.log have.

Comment: You have to setup permissions as the Install documentation for laravel states.

Comment: yes that solved my problem, but i have to recursively set permission @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: `-R` flag means recursive, so it should set permission recursively. I'm glad it works. )

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexeyMezenin mentioned, you have a database problem. Check the name of your database. Is it really 'blogg' or should it be 'blog'? Check your .env file accordingly.